# On $n$-th prime $\pmod {n}$

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Has it been proved or disproved that for any fixed $a\geq 1$ there are infinitelly many primes $p_n\equiv a\pmod{n}$?
I believe i have  proved  that for every $a\geq1$ there are infinitelly many natural numbers $m$ with $m\equiv a\pmod{\pi(m)}$ where $\pi(m)$ is the prime counting function and i was wondering if  this can be also true for a smallest subset of $\mathbb{N}$ (the  primes).

OEIS does not tell much.http://oeis.org/A004648
Any reference would be appreciated.
Thank you for viewing.

Comment: How did you prove that $m\equiv a\pmod{\pi(m)}$ has infinitely many solutions $m$ for any fixed $a$?

Comment: @Michael Zieve using the fact that $\pi(m)=\omicron(m)$ and that $\pi(m+1) -\pi(m)=0$ or $1$. If you  divide  $m-a$ with $\pi(m)$ the residue must be sometimes zero because if not,   $\frac{m-a}{\pi(m)}$ will be always too small.In fact i believe that this same argument could be applied not only to a fixed $a$ but to any slowly increasing sequence $a(m)$ of natural numbers as well.But this is just hypothetical.